# Rules being overwriten on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create some rules using `.htaccess`:

i would like to do:

- `blog/`[specific-page-title] : should be a mask of `src/components/blog/index.php`
- [category]/[specific-module-url] : should be a mask of `./index.php`
- [specific-module-url] : should be a mask of `./index.php`

The `.htaccess`file content is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# RULES FOR BLOG

RewriteRule blog/(.+)$                      ./src/components/blog/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# RULES FOR LANDING PAGE

RewriteRule ([a-z\-_0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$        index.php?module=$1&url=$2 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ([^/.]+)$                       index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

**The problem is**

Always it's redirect to `./index.php` - i can't access blog.

How i can make the rules not be overwriten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `^` start anchor on your rules so they match URLs that they shouldn't:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# RULES FOR BLOG

RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$                      ./src/components/blog/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# RULES FOR LANDING PAGE

RewriteRule ^([a-z\-_0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$        index.php?module=$1&url=$2 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$                       index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC]
```